# In SSRS dynamically insert Name column in Catalog table (report server db) from a parameter value

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have existing 5 SSRS reports each having a Summary and Detail RDL(Total 10). We are planning to consolidate all the **summary** reports into one. Detail will remain as it is. Currently, the detail procedure uses the  Catalog table of the report server to determine what parameters user selected while in the summary report. Basically, from the catalog table it picks up Name of the report and user id to determine the parameters from the session.

**Question**: Since we are consolidating into one RDL, the report names won't be there anymore. **Is there a way I can insert the Name dynamically through the code in Catalog table(report server db) depending on what parameter user has selected from the dropdown to open the report**.

I am really stuck at this. Can anybody please help.

I am thinking of creating a new parameter in summary report and storing where condition dynamically depending on what parameter user has selected and then send the full parameter value to the detail procedure. This would remove the dependency on Catalog table. Any thoughts on this or any better way to it?

Comment: You probably need to show the parameter(s) and how they are passed between reports currently, it's not clear from your question (to me). I never heard of using the catalog table to this purpose so it maybe there is an alternative.

Comment: I can't give the parameters right now.This is the gist of how it works. 1.We get the MAX of logentryid from executionlogstorage table (inner join with catalog table on itemid with a where condition on the user id and report name). 2. Use that logentryid to get the executionid from executionlogstorage table. 3. Use that executionid to get the latest snapshotdataid from sessiondata table. 4. Then finally use the snapshotdataid to get the queryparams column from the snapshotdata table. So that is how we get the parameters selected by user then we pass this queryparams in the detail procedure.

Comment: If its not possible to update the Name column in catalog table, I can only think of creating a parameter (named where) in summary report  and pass it to the detail report from the action property.    Something like you have helped me with this question below:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51446620/in-ssrs-how-to-create-a-dynamic-where-condition-using-multi-value-parameters/51451175#51451175

Comment: why can you not just pass the parameters from the main report to the sub report as SSRS was designed? I might be wrong, but as with your previous question, it sounds like you are over complicating things when there might be a simple solution.

Comment: Yes I think that's the way to go. The thing is its designed right now through cache table and to pass individual parameters I will have to make changes to multiple procedures and at multiple places.